# How do I configure DScintilla to highlight Lua with certain style attributes?

Tags: delphi, colors, lua, scintilla

I'm trying to replicate the syntax highlighting style for Lua shown here:

[image]

I'm using DScintilla, the VLC component to support Scintilla in Delphi. I read every single module of Dscintilla to see the functions and get what I was looking for, and I have already done the following:

- margins (colour, number, width, etc.)
- colorize =, >, <,etc
- colorize numbers
- colorize comments
- colorize strings with '...'

The problem now is that I can't change the comment style to italic, or colorize conditionals (if, else, then, while, etc.) from [the lexer of Lua that Scintilla has](http://scintilla.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/scintilla/scite/src/lua.properties?view=markup),
or colorize variables.

My current code, the one which works, is this:

```
with EditScript do
begin
  SetScrollWidth(430); //so we don't see it
  Margins.Right := 1;
  Margins.Left := 0;
  Margins.Top := 0;
  Margins.Bottom := 0;
  SetMarginLeft(5);
  SetMarginWidthN(0, 40);
  SetMarginWidthN(1, 0);
  SetExtraAscent(4); //space between lines

  //-----------------------margin line numbers
  StyleSetFont(STYLE_LINENUMBER, 'Default');
  StyleSetBold(STYLE_LINENUMBER, true);
  StyleSetBack(STYLE_LINENUMBER, gray);
  StyleSetFore(STYLE_LINENUMBER, clWebBlack);

  //-----------------------Text
  StyleSetFont(STYLE_DEFAULT, 'Courier New'); 
  //TO DO: variables and comments in cursive
  SetLexerLanguage('Lua');
  SetLexer(SCLEX_LUA);
  SetCodePage(CP_UTF8);

  //-----------------------Colours
  StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE, green_comments);
  StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_NUMBER, blue_numbers);
  StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_CHARACTER, red_strings);
  StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_OPERATOR, green_conditionals);
end;
```

what doesn't work? this:

```
//-----------------------Italics
StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_DEFAULT, true);
StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE, true);
StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_COMMENTDOC, true);
```

or

```
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_COMMENT, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_COMMENTDOC, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_STRING, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_PREPROCESSOR, clGreen);
// StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER, clGreen); //it highlights everything, wtf?
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_STRINGEOL, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD2, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD3, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD4, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD5, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD6, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD7, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD8, clGreen);
StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_LABEL, clGreen);
```

If I call `ShowMessage(EditScript.DescribeKeyWordSets)`, I get the following:

```
Keywords
Basic functions
String, (table) & math functions
(coroutines), I/O & system facilities
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Comment: I just tried this using wxlua and I get both setting style color and setting italic attribute to work. What version of Scintilla are you using? Do you get any error or just no visible difference?

Comment: I do not get any error, since Scintilla has a good "if not valid value then end without errors", but I don't see visible differences. I am using the latest DScintilla from http://code.google.com/p/dscintilla/ and last SciLexer.dll (version 3.3.2)

Comment: This is very recent. I've seen some bindings to take 1/0 instead of true/false. Also, if you can't get Italic attribute to work, you can always use StyleSetFont with a font that has Italic style.

Comment: Although I could do that, I can not fix the lexer problem with these special words "while,else,if,begin,end,etc." which are in the link I posted (inside Scintilla)

Comment: @PaulKulchenko­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: I don't have much more to contribute unfortunately; I have tested your exact commands and they work for me (using Scintilla 3.2.3). I don't have access to DScintilla and it seems like your API calls look correct.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko do keywords and variable names work also for you? I mean "else, if,while,etc" and the purple variable names in the picture. Thanks for trying to help also Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have tried a lot of combinations and ended up with this one "semi"-working.
Before writing the setItalic if I write the SetFont for that style it will work in most cases, something like this:

```
  StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE, 'Courier New');
  StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE,10);

  StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE,true);  // "--..."
```

So now the *ONLY* problem would be **keywords** and **variable names** (in purple in the picture)

**@Edited:**
here is how it looks like now:
[image]

and here is the code I used:

```
  with EditScript do
  begin
    SetScrollWidth(430); //so we don't see it
    Margins.Right:=1;
    Margins.Left:=0;
    Margins.Top:=0;
    Margins.Bottom:=0;
    SetMarginLeft(5);
    SetMarginWidthN(0,40);
    SetMarginWidthN(1,0);
    SetExtraAscent(4); //space between lines

    //-----------------------margin line numbers
    StyleSetFont(STYLE_LINENUMBER, 'Default');
    StyleSetBold(STYLE_LINENUMBER, true);
    StyleSetBack(STYLE_LINENUMBER, gray);
    StyleSetFore(STYLE_LINENUMBER,clWebBlack);

    //-----------------------Text
    SetLexerLanguage('Lua');  //don't work
      SetLexer(SCLEX_LUA);
      SetCodePage(CP_UTF8);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_DEFAULT, 'Courier New');
      StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_DEFAULT,10);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER, 'Courier New');
      StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER,10);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE, 'Courier New');
      StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE,10);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_WORD, 'Courier New');
      StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_WORD,10);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING, 'Courier New');
      StyleSetSize(SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING,10);
      StyleSetFont(SCE_LUA_COMMENTDOC, 'Courier New');

     //-----------------------Italics
      StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE,true);  // "--..."
      StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING,true);   // "[[...]]"
      StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER,true);   // "variables"
      StyleSetBold(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER,true);
      StyleSetBold(SCE_LUA_WORD,true);   //init start/end true false
      StyleSetItalic(SCE_LUA_COMMENTDOC,true); //don't work

     //-----------------------KeyWords
      SetKeyWords(0, 'if then else init start end true false');

     //-----------------------Colours
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_COMMENTLINE, green_comments);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_COMMENTDOC, green_comments);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_NUMBER, blue_numbers);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_CHARACTER, red_strings);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_OPERATOR, green_conditionals);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING, green_comments);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER, purple);
      StyleSetFore(SCE_LUA_WORD, blue_strings);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only with keywords and variable names, it seems like it comes down to two things:

1. You need to use `SetKeyWords` call to assign whatever keywords you have to those groups that correspond to `SCE_LUA_WORD` and `SCE_LUA_WORD#` groups. For example, `editor:SetKeyWords(0,"if then else")`.
2. For variable names it seems like you may need to use `SCE_LUA_IDENTIFIER` and color everything else in a different color. In my case, setting `editor:StyleSetForeground(wxstc.wxSTC_LUA_IDENTIFIER, wx.wxColour(127, 0, 0))` correctly colors only variables used.

Comment: are you kidding me? do I have to write every single keyword even when it is writen inside Scintilla? (http://scintilla.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/scintilla/scite/src/lua.properties?view=markup)... w/e, anyway thanks for everything, I'll set my answer as accepted, and  +1 yours, cause it is also a solution to the problem (but not the definitive). are you ok with that?

Comment: @user2308704, yes, see http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETKEYWORDS. That's your question, so whatever works for you ;)